# Android intent filter pathPattern doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

Let's say i have two urls and I want to take the user to different activities based on the url pathPattern since both of them have the same pathPrefix.

> URL1: /Reviews/xxx-SRCH_xxx.htm
>
> URL2: /Reviews/xxx-Eyyy.htm

xxx: alphabets with no max. limit (ie. it could be as short as 2)

yyy: is numbers with no max. limit.

I want to look for `SRCH_` in URL1 and take the user to Activity1 and look for `-E[0-9].htm` in URL2 to take them to Activity2.

There's not much documentation I could find.

> These attributes are meaningful only if the scheme and host attributes are also specified for the filter.

Things I tried.

```
 <activity android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.ui.activities.HomeActivity"
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="www.mycompany.com" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/Reviews/" />
        <data android:pathPattern="/.*-E*\\.htm" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

```
    <android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.ui.activities.DetailsActivity"
    <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="www.mycompany.com" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/Reviews/" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*-SRCH_*.*\\.htm />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The problem I'm having is that when I click either of those urls, it shows two instances of my app icon (I assume it corresponds to each activity).

Comment: I have a solution for what you want,but by handling yourself,I'm not familiar with pathPattern

Comment: @MahDi yea that's my last recourse by directing everything to one Activity and use regex to distinguish the urls and take the user to Activity1 vs Activity2 based on the result. But I would think there's an easier way to handle it using pathPattern.